# how to check my answer is wrong or right when click on button?

Tags: android, database, button

i am working on android quiz. i have 4 buttons and logic in that to check whether my answer is right or wrong when click on any button. but its not working.

```
public class QuestionActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private Question currentQ;
    private GamePlay currentGame;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.question);
        /**
         * Configure current game and get question
         */
        currentGame = ((CYKApplication)getApplication()).getCurrentGame();
        currentQ = currentGame.getNextQuestion();
        Button nextBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        nextBtn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button nextBtn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        nextBtn2.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button nextBtn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        nextBtn3.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button nextBtn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
        nextBtn4.setOnClickListener(this);
        /**
         * Update the question and answer options..
         */
        setQuestions();

    }


    /**
     * Method to set the text for the question and answers from the current games
     * current question
     */
    private void setQuestions() {
        //set the question text from current question
        String question = Utility.capitalise(currentQ.getQuestion());
        TextView qText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
        qText.setText(question);

        //set the available options
        List<String> answers = currentQ.getQuestionOptions();
        TextView option1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        option1.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(0)));

        TextView option2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        option2.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(1)));

        TextView option3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        option3.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(2)));

        TextView option4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
        option4.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(3)));
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        //Log.d("Questions", "Moving to next question");

    if(!checkAnswer()) return;
        /**
         * check if end of game
         */
        if (currentGame.isGameOver()){
            //Log.d("Questions", "End of game! lets add up the scores..");
            //Log.d("Questions", "Questions Correct: " + currentGame.getRight());
            //Log.d("Questions", "Questions Wrong: " + currentGame.getWrong());
            Intent i = new Intent(this, EndgameActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
        else{
            Intent i = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        switch (keyCode)
        {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK :
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    /*
      Check if a checkbox has been selected, and if it
      has then check if its correct and update gamescore
     */
    private boolean checkAnswer() {
        String answer = getSelectedAnswer();
        if (answer==null){
            //Log.d("Questions", "No Checkbox selection made - returning");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            //Log.d("Questions", "Valid Checkbox selection made - check if correct");
            if (currentQ.getAnswer().equalsIgnoreCase(answer))
            {
                //Log.d("Questions", "Correct Answer!");
                currentGame.incrementScore();
            }
            else{
                //Log.d("Questions", "Incorrect Answer!");
                currentGame.decrementScore();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }



    private String getSelectedAnswer() {
        Button c1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        Button c2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        Button c3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        Button c4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer4);
        if (c1.callOnClick())
        {
            return c1.getContext().toString();
        }
        if (c2.callOnClick())
        {
            return c2.getContext().toString();
        }
        if (c3.callOnClick())
        {
            return c3.getContext().toString();
        }
        if (c4.callOnClick())
        {
            return c4.getContext().toString();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

log cat-

```
09-02 08:17:30.083: E/Trace(2148): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
    09-02 08:17:30.193: D/dalvikvm(2148): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 65K, 8% free 2413K/2620K, paused 26ms, total 28ms
    09-02 08:17:30.203: I/dalvikvm-heap(2148): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.553MB for 2160016-byte allocation
    09-02 08:17:30.313: D/dalvikvm(2148): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 5% free 4521K/4732K, paused 104ms, total 104ms
    09-02 08:17:30.363: D/dalvikvm(2148): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 4521K/4732K, paused 4ms+3ms, total 50ms
    09-02 08:17:30.832: D/gralloc_goldfish(2148): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
    09-02 08:17:35.432: D/dalvikvm(2148): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 17K, 4% free 4988K/5148K, paused 42ms, total 45ms
    09-02 08:17:35.482: I/dalvikvm-heap(2148): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.068MB for 2160016-byte allocation
    09-02 08:17:35.562: D/dalvikvm(2148): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4K, 3% free 7092K/7260K, paused 4ms+4ms, total 77ms
    09-02 08:17:36.512: I/Choreographer(2148): Skipped 764 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    09-02 08:17:38.682: I/dalvikvm(2148): threadid=1: stack overflow on call to Landroid/view/View;.findViewById:LI
    09-02 08:17:38.682: I/dalvikvm(2148):   method requires 12+20+8=40 bytes, fp is 0x4205a320 (32 left)
    09-02 08:17:38.682: I/dalvikvm(2148):   expanding stack end (0x4205a300 to 0x4205a000)
    09-02 08:17:38.682: I/dalvikvm(2148): Shrank stack (to 0x4205a300, curFrame is 0x4205fec4)
    09-02 08:17:38.682: D/AndroidRuntime(2148): Shutting down VM
    09-02 08:17:38.682: W/dalvikvm(2148): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148): java.lang.StackOverflowError
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.view.ViewGroup.findViewTraversal(ViewGroup.java:3053)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.view.View.findViewById(View.java:15104)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.view.ViewGroup.findViewTraversal(ViewGroup.java:3053)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.view.View.findViewById(View.java:15104)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.view.ViewGroup.findViewTraversal(ViewGroup.java:3053)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.view.View.findViewById(View.java:15104)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.view.ViewGroup.findViewTraversal(ViewGroup.java:3053)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.view.View.findViewById(View.java:15104)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.view.Window.findViewById(Window.java:900)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1839)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.starchazer.cyk.QuestionActivity.getSelectedAnswer(QuestionActivity.java:144)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.starchazer.cyk.QuestionActivity.checkAnswer(QuestionActivity.java:126)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.starchazer.cyk.QuestionActivity.onClick(QuestionActivity.java:85)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.view.View.callOnClick(View.java:4222)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.starchazer.cyk.QuestionActivity.getSelectedAnswer(QuestionActivity.java:148)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.starchazer.cyk.QuestionActivity.checkAnswer(QuestionActivity.java:126)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.starchazer.cyk.QuestionActivity.onClick(QuestionActivity.java:85)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.view.View.callOnClick(View.java:4222)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.cyk.QuestionActivity.getSelectedAnswer(QuestionActivity.java:148)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.cyk.QuestionActivity.checkAnswer(QuestionActivity.java:126)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.cyk.QuestionActivity.onClick(QuestionActivity.java:85)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.view.View.callOnClick(View.java:4222)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.cyk.QuestionActivity.getSelectedAnswer(QuestionActivity.java:148)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.cyk.QuestionActivity.checkAnswer(QuestionActivity.java:126)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.cyk.QuestionActivity.onClick(QuestionActivity.java:85)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.view.View.callOnClick(View.java:4222)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.cyk.QuestionActivity.getSelectedAnswer(QuestionActivity.java:148)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.cyk.QuestionActivity.checkAnswer(QuestionActivity.java:126)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.cyk.QuestionActivity.onClick(QuestionActivity.java:85)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.view.View.callOnClick(View.java:4222)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.cyk.QuestionActivity.getSelectedAnswer(QuestionActivity.java:148)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.cyk.QuestionActivity.checkAnswer(QuestionActivity.java:126)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.cyk.QuestionActivity.onClick(QuestionActivity.java:85)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.view.View.callOnClick(View.java:4222)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.cyk.QuestionActivity.getSelectedAnswer(QuestionActivity.java:148)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.cyk.QuestionActivity.checkAnswer(QuestionActivity.java:126)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.cyk.QuestionActivity.onClick(QuestionActivity.java:85)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.view.View.callOnClick(View.java:4222)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.cyk.QuestionActivity.getSelectedAnswer(QuestionActivity.java:148)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.cyk.QuestionActivity.checkAnswer(QuestionActivity.java:126)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.cyk.QuestionActivity.onClick(QuestionActivity.java:85)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.view.View.callOnClick(View.java:4222)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.cyk.QuestionActivity.getSelectedAnswer(QuestionActivity.java:148)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.cyk.QuestionActivity.checkAnswer(QuestionActivity.java:126)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.cyk.QuestionActivity.onClick(QuestionActivity.java:85)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.view.View.callOnClick(View.java:4222)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.cyk.QuestionActivity.getSelectedAnswer(QuestionActivity.java:148)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.cyk.QuestionActivity.checkAnswer(QuestionActivity.java:126)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.cyk.QuestionActivity.onClick(QuestionActivity.java:85)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.view.View.callOnClick(View.java:4222)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.cyk.QuestionActivity.getSelectedAnswer(QuestionActivity.java:148)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.cyk.QuestionActivity.checkAnswer(QuestionActivity.java:126)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.cyk.QuestionActivity.onClick(QuestionActivity.java:85)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.view.View.callOnClick(View.java:4222)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.cyk.QuestionActivity.getSelectedAnswer(QuestionActivity.java:148)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.cyk.QuestionActivity.checkAnswer(QuestionActivity.java:126)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.cyk.QuestionActivity.onClick(QuestionActivity.java:85)
    09-02 08:17:39.092: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.view.V
    09-02 08:17:39.122: D/dalvikvm(2148): GC_CONCURRENT freed 762K, 11% free 7907K/8812K, paused 69ms+5ms, total 117ms
    09-02 08:17:39.122: D/dalvikvm(2148): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 16ms
    09-02 08:22:39.222: I/Process(2148): Sending signal. PID: 2148 SIG: 9
    09-02 08:22:39.783: E/Trace(2182): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
    09-02 08:22:39.883: D/dalvikvm(2182): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 68K, 9% free 2413K/2624K, paused 25ms, total 27ms
    09-02 08:22:39.893: I/dalvikvm-heap(2182): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.553MB for 2160016-byte allocation
    09-02 08:22:40.013: D/dalvikvm(2182): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 5% free 4521K/4736K, paused 114ms, total 114ms
    09-02 08:22:40.063: D/dalvikvm(2182): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 4521K/4736K, paused 4ms+3ms, total 49ms
    09-02 08:22:40.513: D/gralloc_goldfish(2182): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

in the above code i am retriving data on four answer buttons from the database. my data is displaying on the buttons. when i click on button i want to check my answer is right or wrong. and after answering its move to the next question whether its right or wrong.

Comment: why buttons are initialized 2 times

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18589522/how-to-solve-errors-related-to-scores-and-proceed-to-next-round-in-android-gener        you can see on this link also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    // NEW: pass the received view to checkAnswer
    if(!checkAnswer(arg0)) return;

    if (currentGame.isGameOver()){
        //Log.d("Questions", "End of game! lets add up the scores..");
        //Log.d("Questions", "Questions Correct: " +            currentGame.getRight());
        //Log.d("Questions", "Questions Wrong: " + currentGame.getWrong());
        Intent i = new Intent(this, EndgameActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
    else{
        Intent i = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
}

// NEW: add view as argument to checkAnswer
private boolean checkAnswer(View v) {

    // NEW: retrieve answer from clicked view
    Button b = (Button)v;
    String answer = b.getText().toString();

    // now check if the answer is correct
    if (currentQ.getAnswer().equalsIgnoreCase(answer))  {
        //Log.d("Questions", "Correct Answer!");
        currentGame.incrementScore();
    }
    else  {
        //Log.d("Questions", "Incorrect Answer!");
        currentGame.decrementScore();
    }
    return true;
}
```

What the code above does is retrieve the view that was clicked and extract it's caption (text), then checks that against the correct answer. Of course since you could also NOT click one of the buttons you will probably need to check if the clicked view is indeed one of the buttons, and if not you should skip the answer checking - I have omitted this in the example code above.

Comment: Appreciate free3dom. for those like to work on quiz with buttons and scores.

Answer (score 0):

put the answer in a string variable & check the button object text is same as in string variable than you are right else wrong.

```
String str = <your answer> ; 
if(<btn object>.getText().toString().equalsTo(str))
  // correct answer
else
  // wrong answer


public class QuestionActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private Question currentQ;
private GamePlay currentGame;
private String str = "" ; // String to hold question

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.question);
    /**
     * Configure current game and get question
     */
    currentGame = ((CYKApplication)getApplication()).getCurrentGame();
    currentQ = currentGame.getNextQuestion();
    Button nextBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
    nextBtn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button nextBtn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
    nextBtn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button nextBtn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
    nextBtn3.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button nextBtn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
    nextBtn4.setOnClickListener(this);
    /**
     * Update the question and answer options..
     */
    setQuestions();

}


/**
 * Method to set the text for the question and answers from the current games
 * current question
 */
private void setQuestions() {
    //set the question text from current question
    String question = Utility.capitalise(currentQ.getQuestion());
    // assign correct answer to str variable.
    str = answer ; 
    TextView qText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    qText.setText(question);

    //set the available options
    List<String> answers = currentQ.getQuestionOptions();
    TextView option1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
    option1.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(0)));

    TextView option2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
    option2.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(1)));

    TextView option3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
    option3.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(2)));

    TextView option4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
    option4.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(3)));
}


@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    //Log.d("Questions", "Moving to next question");

if(!checkAnswer()) return;
    /**
     * check if end of game
     */
    if (currentGame.isGameOver()){
        //Log.d("Questions", "End of game! lets add up the scores..");
        //Log.d("Questions", "Questions Correct: " + currentGame.getRight());
        //Log.d("Questions", "Questions Wrong: " + currentGame.getWrong());
        Intent i = new Intent(this, EndgameActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
    else{
        Intent i = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
}




@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    switch (keyCode)
    {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK :
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}


/*
  Check if a checkbox has been selected, and if it
  has then check if its correct and update gamescore
 */
private boolean checkAnswer() {
    String answer = getSelectedAnswer();
    if (answer==null){
        //Log.d("Questions", "No Checkbox selection made - returning");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        //Log.d("Questions", "Valid Checkbox selection made - check if correct");
        if (currentQ.getAnswer().equalsIgnoreCase(answer))
        {
            //Log.d("Questions", "Correct Answer!");
            currentGame.incrementScore();
        }
        else{
            //Log.d("Questions", "Incorrect Answer!");
            currentGame.decrementScore();
        }
        return true;
    }
}



private String getSelectedAnswer() {
    Button c1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer1);
    Button c2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer2);
    Button c3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer3);
    Button c4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer4);
    if (c1.callOnClick())
    {
        return c1.getContext().toString();
    }
    if (c2.callOnClick())
    {
        return c2.getContext().toString();
    }
    if (c3.callOnClick())
    {
        return c3.getContext().toString();
    }
    if (c4.callOnClick())
    {
        return c4.getContext().toString();
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: how and where i include this code in my code? basically i am retriving my data from database.

Comment: i am retriving questions and answers from database. so dont know what to write in                                                 str=answer;                                                     String str = <your answer> ;                                    if(<btn object>.getText().toString().equalsTo(str))

Comment: assign the correct answer to str variable among all 4 answers which are you fetching from database. You must know correct answer.

Comment: bro. you can see in public boolean checkAnswer() i am getting correct via currentQ.getAnswer(). so how can i assign the correct answer from database.

Comment: let me tell you one thing if you know plz help me. if i remove call to checkAnswer() method in onCreate method. my game work in that case. but as there's no call to checkAnswer() its not check my answer right or wrong. on the other hand if i add call to that method lots of errors and my game stopped working when i answer the first question and then restart.

Comment: assign currentQ.getAnswer() to str.

Comment: i have four buttons for answers so i have to edit this code four times?                                                          String str = <your answer> ; 
if(<btn object>.getText().toString().equalsTo(str))
  // correct answer
else
  // wrong answer

Comment: bhai plz help kar de.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
c2.getContext().toString();
```

to

```
 c2.getText().toString();
```

So this should be

```
 private String getSelectedAnswer() {
    Button c1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer1);
    Button c2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer2);
    Button c3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer3);
    Button c4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer4);
    if (c1.callOnClick())
    {
        return c1.getText().toString();
    }
    if (c2.callOnClick())
    {
        return c2.getText().toString();
    }
    if (c3.callOnClick())
    {
        return c3.getText().toString();
    }
    if (c4.callOnClick())
    {
        return c4.getText().toString();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: i have tried this. still my app stopped working after first answer.

Comment: Okay please post log cat so I can see what's causing the problem.

Comment: actually log cat showing nothing i am sending you the class file related to the file i sent earlier. text for question answers coming from database.

Comment: public int getScore() {
  return score;
 }
 public void setScore(int score) {
  this.score = score;
 }                                                      public void addQuestions(Question q) {
  this.questions.add(q);
 }
 public List<Question> getQuestions() {
  return questions;
 }
 
 public Question getNextQuestion()
              {  Question next = questions.get(this.getRound());
  this.setRound(this.getRound()+1);
  return next;
 }
  public void incrementScore(){
  score=score+100;
 }
 public void decrementScore()
 {
  score=score-50;
 }

Comment: when i answer the first question app stop working and showing error in log cat WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC block 20 or something ms

Comment: In QuestionActivity class when i remove call to checkAnswer() method from onClick() method my game work. but then my game not check my answer right or wrong. on the other hand if i am not remove call to this method. my game works and after answering first question my app stop working and restart.